# Android GeoFencing Dwell

Tags: android, location

I want to detect when a user is visiting a place for more then about 10 minutes.
The user has to give a location in advance that he/she wants to track visits to.

I'm wondering about the best way to implement this.
In Android geofencing I am aware of the "dwell" type, but I'm wondering if this causes a battery drain.

Talking to some people, I hear iOS has something called "visits". Is there an Android counterpart?

I am aware that my question is broad, but I just need to be pointed in the right direction.

**Summary**
Best way to detect when a user "visits" a place which is not too aggressive on the battery.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best way to do, since the Geofencing service should do this kind of battery optimizations. It's not an answer, but the documentation points to a "battery saving" sugestion for Geofencing

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/Geofence.Builder.html#setNotificationResponsiveness%28int%29

Maybe you could try to set a higher value to reduce the consumption if you do not need any additional feedback to the user at the moment he visits the destination.

I guess you could also try to measure how much your app is consuming using this. You can easily track the battery usage per app since Android 5, if I'm not wrong.

So you could try to leave the device, unused for a whole day, and check the battery usage. 
Then create the geofence and check the usage for your app and GooglePlayServices, and check the difference. Although it will be a bit hard since other apps may be responsible for the difference, I think this would be the first step.